# Install linked C library with python package

Tags: python, distutils, python-c-extension

I have a project that builds a C library `_a`, which has python bindings that are used in `a.py`. During the build, `_a` links to `libdepend`, which is also built using my build system.

I have a `setup.py` file using distutils that builds an `Extension` and uses `setup`:

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
# Set up extension
extension = Extension('_a',
                      ['a.c'],
                      # Where the built library  is
                      library_dirs=[library_build_dir],
                      libraries=['libdepend']
                      )

# Set up python module
setup(name='a',
      ext_modules=[extension],
      py_modules=['a']
      )
```

When I run `python setup.py install`, `_a` is copied to my `site-packages` folder, but I can't seem to get `libdepend` to be copied. If I try to import `a`, I get

```
import a
# >>> ImportError: libdepend.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Is there a way to copy `libdepend` to my `site-packages` folder with distutils? I would like to do this since my build system is building `libdepend` as well. I know I could install `libdepend` globally, but I would like the option to be able to install it to a user's virtualenv site packages.

In my specific case, I'm using CMake as the build system and `a.c` is actually a binding generated by SWIG. I'm trying to find a solution that will work at least with Linux and OS X/Mac OS, but preferably with Windows as well.

Comment: please specify OS. shared library rules and linker rules are OS dependant.

Comment: My current testing environment is Linux, but I would like a solution that's portable to at least OS X/MacOS and preferably Windows as well.